# $(window).resize(); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions that requires `$(window).resize();` & `$(document).ready();` to work.

I am trying to optimize the code and make shorter by removing the duplicate of  `$(window).resize();` & `$(document).ready();` and only show it once in the file and just wrap all the functions that needs them within them.

For example,

```
function onResize(){

   //Grid system
   var gridElement = $(".gridElement", "#grid3");
   function GalleryGrid() {
      var grid3 = $('#grid3');
      var width = $(window).width();
      if (width < 1024 && width > 770) {
         var grid1 = $('#grid1');
         var grid2 = $('#grid2');

         for (var i = 0; i < gridElement.length; i++) {
            if (i < gridElement.length / 2) {
               grid1.append(gridElement[i]);
            } else {
               grid2.append(gridElement[i]);
            }
         }
      } else {
         grid3.append(gridElement);
      }
   }

   //Full screen
   function fullScreen() {
       var newHeight = $("html").height() + "px";
       $(".fullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
   }
}

$(document).ready(onResize);
$(window).resize(onResize);
```

The whole code is wrapped with `$(document).ready(function(){`

However, all my attempts around this approach is breaking the code, especially the Gridsystem... it is simply not working, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can replace `$(document).ready(onResize);` with `onResize()` here.

Comment: I don't see where you call GalleryGrid function

Comment: @dystroy the file will may have other functions that does not require on resize

Comment: Where do you call the functions you've defined inside your function? You define `fullScreen()` and `GalleryGrid()` but you don't call those. There's definitely something wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to execute the onResize() function when the resize event is received.  You seem to be a bit out of sync with how the document-ready stuff is intended to work -- and I recommend that you read some of the basic jquery tutorials -- but, basically, you want to use the function in $(function()....) to apply the event handler to the window after the document is fully loaded.

Here, you seem to be -- mistakenly -- assuming that your running $(window).resize... after calling $(docyument).ready...would have waited until the .ready() function executed, but that's not how that works.  The code that should be executed after the document reaches the fully-loaded state should go into the function parameter to $().

Basically, you want to put your event handler assignment in the .ready() function like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(onResize);
});
```

Comment: You don't have to wait for DOM ready to bind events to the `window` object, since it exists before the DOM has finished loading.

Comment: I'm afraid BergBrains that your answer is incorrect and _I recommend that you read some of the basic [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) tutorials_, but basically you can assign the `onresize` handler to the `window` because it is always available.

Comment: Looks like you're right, guys!  I guess this follows, as the window is always present. Thanks for clarifying.

That said, you might consider implementing this within the doc ready handler anyway, and then just chaining .resize() to trigger the event, executing the handler, changing my code above to:

    $(function() {
        $(window).resize(onResize).resize();
    });

In general, I consider it good practice to consolidate all of this type of code in the doc ready block.